# `use-package` :defer prevents :mode from actually inserting something in auto-mode-alist

Tags: use-package, auto-mode-alist

In my `init.el`, I have something like

```lisp
(use-package racket-mode
  :mode "\\.rkt\\'")
```

However, when I open a `.rkt` file, `racket-mode` does not start. Running `(alist-get "\\.rkt\\'" auto-mode-alist nil nil #'equal)` returns `scheme-mode` (because it hooks too on the `.rkt` file extension, God knows why every Lisp dialect hooks into each-other extensions...), so I though maybe it "overwrites" `racket-mode`, ie. it was added after `racket-mode` in `auto-mode-alist`.
However, I have ruled that out with

```lisp
(require 'dash)
(-filter (lambda (x) (equal (car x) "\\.rkt\\'")) auto-mode-alist)
```

which only shows `(("\\.rkt\\'" . scheme-mode))`.

If, then, I:

- manually run `racket-mode` once, or
- I re-execute any `(use-package racket-mode)`, or
- <kbd>M-x</kbd>`load-file` `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

it works, in the sense that opening a `.rkt` file loads the `racket-mode`, and `(alist-get "\\.rkt\\'" auto-mode-alist nil nil #'equal)` returns `racket-mode`. So it seems that forcing `racket-mode` to load makes `use-package` insert it in the `auto-mode-alist`. However, I don't understand why re-calling `use-package`, or re-evaluating the `init.el` file would do that...

---

Reading the documentation of the `:mode` keyword of `use-package`, it says that it implies `:defer`, so that the addition to the `auto-mode-alist` is deferred until actually required.
I tried adding

```lisp
(use-package racket-mode
  :mode "\\.rkt\\'"
  :commands racket-mode)
```

because I read somewhere that could help, but it did not.

---

In a last, desperate measure, I tried

```lisp
(use-package racket-mode
  :init
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rkt\\'" . racket-mode)))
```

but that didn't work either. It almost looks like this code doesn't get executed, because if I launch a fresh emacs instance with `emacs -q`, then eval

```lisp
(require 'use-package)
(use-package racket-mode)
```

it Just Works™. So it's just as if the `use-package` in my `init.el` was simply not executed... Btw, just to be clear: I am *sure* my `init.el` file is evaluated, since it changes the theme, a lot of key bindings and what is shown first when opening Emacs.

---

#### Edit: set `use-package-verbose` as recommended in the comments.

The result is, indeed, strange. My `init.el` file contains the following snippet:

```lisp
(use-package lsp-haskell)
(use-package racket-mode
  :mode "\\.rkt\\'")
(use-package scheme-complete)
```

but in the `*Messages*`, I see the following:

```
Loading package lsp-haskell...done
Loading package scheme-complete...done
```

So it really seems like it simply skips `racket-mode`. Searching for `racket-mode` in the rest of the log did not reveal any match.

Comment: Given the last paragraph - how are you loading use-package into your init files?

Comment: You can get insight into what `use-package` is doing by placing point at the end of the `(use-package racket-mode ...)` form and doing `M-x pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`.  It seems that it does `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rkt\\'" . racket-mode))` whether or not `:defer` is non-nil.

Comment: I don't see scheme-mode registered for the `.rkt` extension. Are you loading `geiser` as well? That seems to associate rkt files with scheme-mode.

Comment: You might try setting `use-package-verbose` in your init file to get some additional detail about when things are happening.

Comment: @mmmmmm I'm not sure what the question is. My init file mostly contains a bunch of `(use-package ...)`.
@glucas I have `geiser` too indeed, even though I'm not too sure about what it does exactly (it was recommended alongside racket-mode and scheme-mode).

Comment: use-package is not part of emacs - how did you install it and get it on your load-path and tell emacs where the use-package macro is defined.?

Comment: @mmmmmm in short, all the package management is made by my distro's package manager, which is in charge of installing all the emacs' packages, put them somewhere and then compile Emacs so that the `load-path` includes the packages' path (the variable is directly set in the C source code). I then call `(package-initialize)` at the top of my `init.el` file which takes care of loading `use-package`.

Comment: After evaluating pieces of my `init.el` file "by-hand", I successfully located the origin of this misbehavior in `quack`. Since I was not sure of what it did when I installed it, and everything seems to work fine without it, I'll just drop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was `quack`, which overwrote `auto-mode-alist` to prefer `scheme-mode` to `racket-mode` when opening `.rkt` files. Disabling it worked perfectly.